# What's the most accurate way to limit FPS on Windows?

Tags: c++

So I'm using a call like:

`Sleep(16 - millisecondsElapsed);`

at the end of every frame draw in my program loop to limit it to 60fps. But if you do the math, `1000ms / 16ms/frames = 62.5frames`, and the way I count frames in my program reflects this. You would need to sleep for ~16.67ms to be accurate. As far as I know, there is no way to sleep for less than a millisecond on Windows.

So what would be the most accurate way to limit FPS?

Comment: You should probably rely on VSync.

Comment: `Sleep()` does not do what you think it does. You are guaranteed that your program will yield its execution for at least `x` ms, so "if you do the math" your FPS can be 50 or 13 or 2, or anything else. What you want is VSync, but since we don't know which API you use, we can't really help. I recommend looking up MSDN.

Comment: Doesn't VSync cap to the refresh rate of the monitor? What if the refresh rate is higher than 60?

Comment: You can specify desired refresh rate when you create fullscreen swap chain.

Comment: In c++11 you can do `std::this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::microseconds(16667))`

Comment: @Kao It won't be any different from invoking Sleep directly.

Comment: @user7860670 Yeah, I just checked the [std::sleep_for source](https://code.woboq.org/gcc/libstdc++-v3/src/c++11/thread.cc.html#213) and yep you are right, thanks for the info.

Comment: "You would need to sleep for ~16.67ms to be accurate."  Have you tried to sleep_for 17 (or even 20) ms?  Does the longer duration work "good enough"?  Can you describe what problem this causes?  Is the issue human visible?   (the human vision system is what it is)  Not sure what timing accuracy has to do with the issue.